# C++ How do I create an array of an inherited class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, struct

C++ Newbie here,

When I was using struct I would do it like this:

```
struct Employee
{
string name;
int id;
}

   struct Company
{
string companyName;
Employee employees[20]
}
```

Now that I am using classes it is confusing for me on how do I create the same array of employees in the Company class. Do I need to inherit employee and do it the same way, should I not inherit it at all. Thanks

Comment: Try `std::vector<Employee> employees`.  Always prefer `std::vector` to an array.

Comment: Hint: class and struct are (almost) the same in c++, only difference being the default access for members, public for structs, private for classes

Comment: See [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class). "The keywords `class` and `struct` are identical except for the default member access and the default base class access."

Comment: Do I need to inherit the Employee class or directly write vector<Employee> employees?

Comment: Use the test:  for inheritance, the test: "is-a".  For example "Company is-a Employee" doesn't work, so inheritance is not recommended.  For containment, use "has-a".  For example "Company has-a Employee" works better, so employee(s) should be a member of Company.

Answer (score 1):

`struct` and `class` are practically identical, pretty much the only difference between them is that:

- in a `struct`, members are `public` by default, and inheriting from a `struct` uses `public` inheritance by default.
- in a `class`, members are `private` by default, and inheriting from a `class` uses `private` inheritance by default.

The following `class` code works exactly the same as the `struct` code:

```
class Employee
{
public:
    string name;
    int id;
};

class Company
{
public:
    string companyName;
    Employee employees[20];
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/DghVnQ)

Comment: I'd add in the sample that also structs can have private/protected members, which is usually not straightforward (and not much used as well)

Comment: Using private/protected members in a struct is just as straightforward as using public members in a class

Comment: I meant is not strightforward for a begineer, as OP seems to be. And actually seldom used I think. 
But I agree with the point, except for the (minor) differences you explained, classes and structs are the same